CORS Policy Blocking Issue with API Gateway (Spring boot and React integration)
i am using api gateway with port no 8080, and when i try to register i get the following issue
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
enter image description here
i have tried with mode 'no-cors', although it does not show the CORS error anymore but i then provides an internal server error
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  });

Here is my application.yml file in the API gateway service
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: PatientService
          uri: lb://PATIENTSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/patient/**
          filters:
            - AuthenticationFilter

        - id: DoctorService
          uri: lb://DOCTORSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/doctor/**
          filters:
            - AuthenticationFilter

        - id: AuthService
          uri: lb://AUTHSERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**

  application:
    name: APIGATEWAY

  server:
    port: 8080

  # Enable global CORS configuration
  http:
    cors:
      allowed-origins: "*"
      allowed-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
      allowed-headers: "*"
      max-age: 3600


